An unexpected error occurred while launching the test runtime
I'm launching the test suite of an eclipse plugin project with org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-surefire-plugin:4.0.7:test.
The process crashes before being able to run any test.
Error on Windows:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-surefire-plugin:4.0.7:test (default-test) on project org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests: An unexpected error occurred while launching the test runtime (process returned error code 1 (HRESULT Code 0x1, check for example https://www.hresult.info/ for further details)). Command-line used to launch the sub-process was C:\Users\nicol\Downloads\jdk-17.0.4_windows-x64_bin\jdk-17.0.4\bin\java.exe -Dosgi.noShutdown=false -Dosgi.os=win32 -Dosgi.ws=win32 -Dosgi.arch=x86_64 -Xmx2048m -Dsdtcore.headless -Dsdtcore.notimeouts -DretryFlakyTests=true -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+UnsyncloadClass -Dosgi.classloader.lock=classname -Dosgi.clean=true -Daj.weaving.verbose=true -Dorg.aspectj.osgi.verbose=true -Dorg.aspectj.weaver.showWeaveInfo=true -jar C:\Users\nicol\.m2\repository\p2\osgi\bundle\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher\1.6.700.v20240213-1244\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher-1.6.700.v20240213-1244.jar -debug -consolelog -data C:\Users\nicol\git\scala-ide\org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests\target\work\data -install C:\Users\nicol\git\scala-ide\org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests\target\work -configuration C:\Users\nicol\git\scala-ide\org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests\target\work\configuration -application org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.headlesstest -testproperties C:\Users\nicol\git\scala-ide\org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests\target\surefire.properties in working directory C:\Users\nicol\git\scala-ide\org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests -> [Help 1]

Same error on linux:
Error:  Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-surefire-plugin:4.0.7:test (default-test) on project org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests: An unexpected error occurred while launching the test runtime (process returned error code 1). Command-line used to launch the sub-process was /opt/hostedtoolcache/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/17.0.10-7/x64/bin/java -Dosgi.noShutdown=false -Dosgi.os=linux -Dosgi.ws=gtk -Dosgi.arch=x86_64 -Xmx2048m -Dsdtcore.headless -Dsdtcore.notimeouts -DretryFlakyTests=true -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+UnsyncloadClass -Dosgi.classloader.lock=classname -Dosgi.clean=true -Daj.weaving.verbose=true -Dorg.aspectj.osgi.verbose=true -Dorg.aspectj.weaver.showWeaveInfo=true -jar /home/runner/.m2/repository/p2/osgi/bundle/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher/1.6.700.v20240213-1244/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher-1.6.700.v20240213-1244.jar -data /home/runner/work/scala-ide/scala-ide/org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests/target/work/data -install /home/runner/work/scala-ide/scala-ide/org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests/target/work -configuration /home/runner/work/scala-ide/scala-ide/org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests/target/work/configuration -application org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.headlesstest -testproperties /home/runner/work/scala-ide/scala-ide/org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests/target/surefire.properties in working directory /home/runner/work/scala-ide/scala-ide/org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests -> [Help 1]

I reduced the pom to a smaller one to remove the sections that have nothing to do with test execution:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemalocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.scala-ide</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.scala-ide.sdt.build</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../org.scala-ide.sdt.build/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests</artifactId>
  <packaging>eclipse-test-plugin</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
          <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
          <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
          <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
          <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
          <testSuite>${project.artifactId}</testSuite>
          <testClass>org.scalaide.TestsSuite</testClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                  <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                </artifactItem>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>

After a google search, I found this issue linked by this one on Github and tried to add <useJDK>BREE</useJDK>, which didn't help.
Also, it appeared that I might need a toolchain configuration, so I created this ~/.m2/toolchains.xml:
<toolchains>
   <toolchain>
      <type>jdk</type>
      <provides>
         <id>JavaSE-17</id>
         <version>17</version>
      </provides>
      <configuration>
         <jdkHome>C:\Users\nicol\Downloads\jdk-17.0.4_windows-x64_bin\jdk-17.0.4</jdkHome>
      </configuration>
   </toolchain>
</toolchains>

But I'm still having the issue. What did I miss ?
With stack trace details:
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-surefire-plugin:4.0.7:test (default-test) on project org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests: An unexpected error occurred while launching the test runtime (process returned error code 1 (HRESULT Code 0x1, check for example https://www.hresult.info/ for further details)). Command-line used to launch the sub-process was C:\Users\nicol\Downloads\jdk-17.0.4_windows-x64_bin\jdk-17.0.4\bin\java.exe -Dosgi.noShutdown=false -Dosgi.os=win32 -Dosgi.ws=win32 -Dosgi.arch=x86_64 -Xmx2048m -Dsdtcore.headless -Dsdtcore.notimeouts -DretryFlakyTests=true -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+UnsyncloadClass -Dosgi.classloader.lock=classname -Dosgi.clean=true -Daj.weaving.verbose=true -Dorg.aspectj.osgi.verbose=true -Dorg.aspectj.weaver.showWeaveInfo=true -jar C:\Users\nicol\.m2\repository\p2\osgi\bundle\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher\1.6.700.v20240213-1244\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher-1.6.700.v20240213-1244.jar -debug -consolelog -data C:\Users\nicol\git\scala-ide\org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests\target\work\data -install C:\Users\nicol\git\scala-ide\org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests\target\work -configuration C:\Users\nicol\git\scala-ide\org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests\target\work\configuration -application org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.headlesstest -testproperties C:\Users\nicol\git\scala-ide\org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests\target\surefire.properties in working directory C:\Users\nicol\git\scala-ide\org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:333)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:52)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:73)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: An unexpected error occurred while launching the test runtime (process returned error code 1 (HRESULT Code 0x1, check for example https://www.hresult.info/ for further details)). Command-line used to launch the sub-process was C:\Users\nicol\Downloads\jdk-17.0.4_windows-x64_bin\jdk-17.0.4\bin\java.exe -Dosgi.noShutdown=false -Dosgi.os=win32 -Dosgi.ws=win32 -Dosgi.arch=x86_64 -Xmx2048m -Dsdtcore.headless -Dsdtcore.notimeouts -DretryFlakyTests=true -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+UnsyncloadClass -Dosgi.classloader.lock=classname -Dosgi.clean=true -Daj.weaving.verbose=true -Dorg.aspectj.osgi.verbose=true -Dorg.aspectj.weaver.showWeaveInfo=true -jar C:\Users\nicol\.m2\repository\p2\osgi\bundle\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher\1.6.700.v20240213-1244\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher-1.6.700.v20240213-1244.jar -debug -consolelog -data C:\Users\nicol\git\scala-ide\org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests\target\work\data -install C:\Users\nicol\git\scala-ide\org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests\target\work -configuration C:\Users\nicol\git\scala-ide\org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests\target\work\configuration -application org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.headlesstest -testproperties C:\Users\nicol\git\scala-ide\org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests\target\surefire.properties in working directory C:\Users\nicol\git\scala-ide\org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.AbstractEclipseTestMojo.runTest (AbstractEclipseTestMojo.java:1054)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.AbstractEclipseTestMojo.runTests (AbstractEclipseTestMojo.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.AbstractTestMojo.execute (AbstractTestMojo.java:233)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:52)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:73)


Have you looked for more detailed output with the -e and -X Maven options? Do you get more messages manually invoking the command line it's showing you?

it gives information about the caller of the command, but not more details (see edit)

The reason is an unsupported jvm argument :
-XX:+UnsyncloadClass

The errors are not output to the console even in debug mode (-e -X).
The java command has to be run separately to see the error:
Unrecognized VM option 'UnsyncloadClass'

